# Compiler message "warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)’"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

I am trying to run a simple C program, but I am getting this error:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’

I am running [Mac OS X v10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) and am compiling in the terminal using [GCC 4.2.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char me[20];

    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s", &me);
    printf("Darn glad to meet you, %s!\n", me);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. It should still produce an executable.

Comment: GCC 4.2.1 was released 2007-07-18. Mountain Lion was released 2012-07-25.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &me);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", me);
```

**Explanation:**

`"%s"` means that `scanf` is expecting a pointer to the first element of a `char` array.

`me` is an array object. Array objects are said to *decay* as a pointer to their first element when passed to a function or used in most expressions except as an argument to `sizeof` and `_Alignof`. So passing `me` or `&me[0]` is equivalent and the preferred way is to simply pass the destination as `me`.

Adding `&` to `me` creates a pointer to arrays of 20 chars, with type `char (*)[20]`, which is different from the type `scanf` expects for `%s`.  The compiler reports the type mismatch but the program probably behaves as you expect because both `&me[0]` and `&me` refer to the same memory location so `scanf()` really receives the correct address, albeit with an incorrect type.

**Code critic:**

Using `"%s"` could cause a buffer overflow if the user inputs a word longer than 19 bytes, so tell `scanf()` to limit the input to 19 bytes by specifying `"%19s"`:

```
scanf("%19s", me);
```

Note also that the return value of `scanf()` is the number of successful conversions, so `1` if input was processed successfully for `%s`, and `0` or `EOF` otherwise.  It is always best to test for `scanf()` failure to read all inputs and only use the destination variables in case of success:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char me[20];

    printf("What is your name?");
    if (scanf("%19s", me) == 1)
        printf("Darn glad to meet you, %s!\n", me);
    else
        printf("Sorry you had to leave!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained *why* too

Comment: Or `..., &me[0])`, if you really want to use the `&` operator.

Comment: @Mike Because... Wait, the compiler warning clearly tells you why.

Comment: @H2CO3 - ah, but if it was clear to Jake, he wouldn't have asked the question. ;)

Comment: I could have improved this further, but was hesitant to because I'm not certain if you'd approve: Basically, an array expression is converted to a pointer expression when a pointer expression is expected, eg. passing to a function.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour the "array object iis evaluated as pointer" could have the same meaning isn't?

Comment: @MOHAMED: *the "array object is evaluated as pointer" could have the same meaning isn't?* not really.  The confusion between arrays and pointers is so widespread and problematic one should be more precise regarding how arrays *decay* into pointers to their first element instead of invoking some *evaluation* side-effect. I took the liberty to amend your answer but feel free to revert this change if you disapprove.

Answer (score 4):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and it will evaluate to the address of the first element in the array.

The array `me` is declared as a 20-element array of `char`; normally, when the *expression* `me` appears in your code, it will be treated as an expression of type "pointer to `char`".  If you had written

```
scanf("%s", me);
```

then you wouldn't have gotten the error; the expression `me` would have been converted to an expression of the correct type.

By using the `&` operator, however, you've bypassed that rule; instead of a pointer to `char`, you're passing a pointer to an *array* of `char` (`char (*)[20]`), which is not what `scanf` expects for the `%s` conversion specifier, hence the diagnostic.

Comment: s/bypassed/taken a different avenue/, or something along those lines, perhaps. Because of the rule, the outcome is different. +1 for the quote, regardless.

Comment: Note: the `_Alignof` was a mistake in N1570, been removed in the standard. That makes sense, because the operand of `_Alignof` is a type, `_Alignof ( type-name )`, not an arbitrary expression.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you please look into this one.The "anomaly" I have  point to is pretty clear.It's about the last token, which is between the last delimiter & the NULL character,rather than 2 delimiters as is  required for a string token--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571060/strtok-issue-if-tokens-are-delimited-by-delimiters-why-is-last-token-between

Comment: @DanielFischer I regret I have to message you this way,I checked your activity and it says you were last seen a minute back and this question was the latest C related activity of yours.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could fix this issue is by doing this:

```
scanf("%s",&me[0]);
```

You actually have to give the array's starting point (which in most languages is 0).