# How to extract the string if we have have more than one delimiters?

Tags: c, string

If I have this code:

```
int main ()
{
char *sentence = "Wisteria#Tunnel";
char stringA[50];
char stringB[50];
char stringC[50];
pDelim = strstr(sentence,"#");
*pDelim = '\0';
strcpy(stringA,sentence);
strcpy(stringB,(pDelim+1));
    return(0);
}
```

After running it, `stringA` will be "Wisteria" and `stringB` will be "Tunnel", right?

If :

```
char *sentence = "Wisteria#Tunnel#Japan";
```

How to extracted it to three part , `stringA` will be "Wisteria" , `stringB` will be "Tunnel" and `stringC` will be "Japan"

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `strtok`.

Comment: Captain Google to the rescue: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: see this.., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571060/strtok-issue-if-tokens-are-delimited-by-delimiters-why-is-last-token-between

Comment: _After running it, stringA will be "Wisteria" and stringB will be "Tunnel", right?_ : Changing the string literal is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Standard string functions `strtok`, `strstr`, `strchr` all will work, provided the surrounding code is correct as well. That is, if you want to search multiple times in the same source string, you need to point a Start-at pointer at the start of your source, and after each (succesful!) search update it to point *after* your delimiter. By default, `strtok` will work fine for your purpose -- a single character delimiter. You can read about `strtok` in any good reference (I'm not going to look it up for you).

In fact it is such a simple operation, I made this up just now. Other than vanilla `strtok`, my `strcpyUpTo` accepts any delimiter string. I could have used `strstr` to first check, but I prefer copying right away. The `strncmp` and `strlen` inside the copy loop may be inefficient; then again, in general these low-level string operations should be pretty fast nevertheless.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strcpyUpTo (const char *source, char *dest, const char *delim)
{
    while (*source && strncmp (source, delim, strlen(delim)))
        *dest++ = *source++;
    *dest = 0;

    if (*source)
        return (char *)(source+strlen(delim));
    return (char *)source;
}

int main (void)
{
    char *sentence = "Wisteria#any#Tunnel#any#Japan";
    char stringA[50];
    char stringB[50];
    char stringC[50];
    char *pDelim;

    pDelim = strcpyUpTo (sentence, stringA, "#any#");
    pDelim = strcpyUpTo (pDelim, stringB, "#any#");
    pDelim = strcpyUpTo (pDelim, stringC, "#any#");

    printf ("stringA = \"%s\"\n", stringA);
    printf ("stringB = \"%s\"\n", stringB);
    printf ("stringC = \"%s\"\n", stringC);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Addition

For an *unknown number of substrings*, you can use a `while` loop such as the following. (For production code, it needs all kinds of checks. Left out for brevity, for clarity, and as exercise for the reader.) It's basically how you'd use `strtok` as well.

```
char resultList[10][50];
int i, n_result;

pDelim = sentence;
n_result = 0;
do
{
    pDelim = strcpyUpTo (pDelim, resultList[n_result], "#any#");
    n_result++;
} while (*pDelim && n_result < 10);

printf ("number of strings: %d\n", n_result);
for (i=0; i<n_result; i++)
    printf ("string %d = \"%s\"\n", i, resultList[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anything more complicated, using `strtok` is the way to go, but you can use `strstr`.  I didn't bother to copy the resultant substrings to new strings, but just printed them to the console. If you wanted to save them, you could either save all of the `b` pointers to an array, or use `strcpy` to make copies.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
  char *sentence = "Wisteria#Tunnel#foo#bar";
  char* b = sentence;
  while(1) {
    char*a = strstr(b,"#");
    if (a) *a = 0;
    printf("%s\n",b);
    if (!a) break;
    b = a+1;
  }
}
```

Output is

`Wisteria
Tunnel
foo
bar`

Comment: For a single character, `strstr` is overkill. Use `strchr`.

Comment: @chouaib - `if (a) *a=0` is to replace the `'#'` char with a null to terminate the string.  This of course clobbers the original string, but the OP did that in the example, so I thought it was ok.

Comment: With indents it would be more visible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char *sentence = "Wisteria#Tunnel#Japan";
    char stringA[50];
    char stringB[50];
    char stringC[50];
    sscanf(sentence, "%49[^#]#%49[^#]#%49[^#]", stringA, stringB, stringC);
    puts(stringA);puts(stringB);puts(stringC);
    return(0);
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split(const char *str, char delimiter){
    char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    const char *p = str;
    int wc = 0;

    for(;;){
        char *pos;
        int len;
        if((pos = strchr(p, delimiter))!=NULL){
            len = pos - p;
            words[wc] = malloc(len+1);
            strncpy(words[wc], p, len);
            words[wc][len] = '\0';
            words=realloc(words, (++wc+1)*sizeof(char*));
        } else {
            pos = strchr(p, '\0');
            len = pos - p + 1;
            words[wc] = malloc(len);
            strncpy(words[wc], p, len);
            words=realloc(words, (++wc+1)*sizeof(char*));
            words[wc] = NULL;//End Mark
            break;
        }
        p = pos + 1;
    }
    return words;
}

int main (){
    char **sentences = split("Wisteria#Tunnel#Japan", '#');
    int i;
    for(i=0;sentences[i];++i){
        puts(sentences[i]);
        free(sentences[i]);
    }
    free(sentences[i]);
    free(sentences);

    return(0);
}
```