# Create a program to print employee details using structures

Tags: c

The code is not printing for name and salary of employee, also not asking for the salary of the employee, kindly mark the wrong items in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct employee{
    int code;
    char name[20];
    int salary;
};

void printEmployeeDetails(struct employee emp);

void printEmployeeDetails(struct employee emp){
    printf("Employee CODE is: %d\n" ,emp.code);
    printf("Employee NAME is: %s\n" ,emp.name);
    printf("Employee SALARy is: %d\n",emp.salary);     

}

int main(){
    struct employee e1;
    printf("Enter your CODE\n");
    scanf("%d",&e1.code);

    printf("Enter your NAME\n");
    scanf("%d",&e1.name);

    printf("Enter your SALARY\n");
    scanf("%d",&e1.salary);

    printEmployeeDetails(e1);

    //printf("The Employee Details Are: \n",printEmployeeDetails(e1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I take that this is a C++ question. You might have turned off compiler warning when compile; as from the compiler warnings (I used onlinegdb compiler), there are a couple issues with your code

First

```cpp
printf("Enter your NAME\n");
scanf("%d",&e1.name);
```

You are expecting `e1.name` to be a string here, so use `"%s"` instead of `"%d"`

Seconly, when using `scanf` for a `char*` variable, you only need to use `scanf("%s", e1.name)` (no need for the `&`)

For more details, read here: [warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570716/warning-format-s-expects-type-char-but-argument-2-has-type-char)

Final

```cpp
printf("Enter your NAME\n");
scanf("%s",e1.name);
```

Comment: `%19s` would be better - stops overflow of the string buffer.